# SignalR: WebSocket security and networking for load balancer

Tags: asp.net, websocket, signalr

We are evaluating SignalR for chat in our web application. Web application runs on a IIS serverfarm behind a Netscaler load balancer. Back plane will be Redis.

1. What are the ports that need to be opened on load balancer to enable Websocket from web browser to web server?
2. Other than enabling sticky session from client, should I need to do anything on the load balancer?
3. SSL is terminated at load balancer. Do we need to do anything additional to enable SSL for websockets?
4. Are there anything I need to do in load balancer for long polling?
5. We are a HIPAA site. Are there any known vulnerabilities in using WebSocket?
6. We create a session cookie after initial authentication, that gets validated on every server request using a global filter in ASP.Net MVC5. Will this global filter gets invoked on every server side method of SignalR?

Comment: DId you figure this out?